# Use wildcards that are stored in table columns in SQL-queries with MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to join two tables in Access based on different wildcards for different rows.

The first, `table1`, contains rows with different wildcards and `table2` contains the column that should be matched with the wildcards in `table1`.

I imagine the SQL code to look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 
ON table2.subject LIKE table1.wildcard
```

The tables look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT72p.jpg

The third pictures shows the result that I want.

How do I execute the join or is there an alternative?

Comment: Great.  Does this work?  What issue do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think MySQL support non-equality conditions for `JOIN`s.  So, you can do this as:

```
SELECT *                  -- first get the matches
FROM table2 as t2,        -- ugg, why doesn't it support CROSS JOIN
     table1 as t1
WHERE t2.subject LIKE t1.wildcard
UNION ALL
SELECT *                  -- then get the non-matches
FROM table2 as t2 LEFT JOIN  
     table1 as t1
     ON 1 = 0             -- always false but gets the same columns
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table1 as t1
                  WHERE t2.subject LIKE t1.wildcard
                 );
```